# Active Record Array array query - to check records that are present in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have an Objective model which has an attribute called as labels whose values are array data type. I need to query all the Objectives whose labels attribute has values that are present in some particular array.

For Example:
I have an array

```
a = ["textile", "blazer"]
```

the `Objective.labels` may have values as `["textile, "ramen"]`

I need to return all objectives that might have either "textile" or "blazer" as one of their labels array values

I tried the following:

```
Objective.where("labels @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ["textile"])
```

This returns some records.Now when I try

```
Objective.where("labels @> ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ["textile", "Blazer"])
```

I expect it to return all Objectives which contains at-least one of the labels array value as textile or blazer.

However, it returns an empty array. Any Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [`&&`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-array.html) overlap  operator.

> overlap (have elements in common)

```
Objective.where("labels && ARRAY[?]::varchar[]", ["textile", "Blazer"])
```

If you have many rows, a GIN index can speed it up.